# Invalid hook call in a react function, ImagePicker and ActionSheet

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I really need some help with hooks in react native...

I have an ActionSheet which onPress one of the options a camera feature should open with  "useCamera" function.

The "useCamera" is in another function(on another file),
using the library "ImagePicker". (specific "ImagePicker.launchCamera")

the "ImagePicker.launchCamera" set the fileUri in the callback while the function return nothing.

So to access the fileUri, I tried to use useState Hook but I get "ERROR: Invalid Hook call.Hooks can only be called inside of the body of the function..."
but the hook inside the function bodY!

**ActionSheet code:**

```
    import {useCamera} from './PhotoHandle';

// export default class EditProfilePic extends React.Component {
function EditProfilePic(props) {
  const [ActionSheetRef, setActionSheetRef] = useState(null);
  const [fileDate, setFileDate] = useState(null);

  return (
    <View style={styles.images_container}>
      <TouchableOpacity
        style={styles.click_edit_icon}
        onPress={() => ActionSheetRef.show()}>
        <Image style={styles.editIcon} source={editIcon} />
      </TouchableOpacity>
      <Image source={props.profileSource} style={styles.image} />
      <ActionSheet
        ref={o => setActionSheetRef(o)}
        title={
          <Text style={{color: '#000', fontSize: 18}}>
            Which one do you like?
          </Text>
        }
        options={['Select from Photos', 'Camera', 'Cancel']}
        cancelButtonIndex={2}
        destructiveButtonIndex={2}
        onPress={index => {
          //camera
          if (index == 1) {
            useCamera()
          }
        }}
      />
    </View>
  );
}
```

**LaunchCamera function:**

```
export function useCamera() {
  const [fileData, setFileData] = useState(null);
  let options = {
    storageOptions: {
      skipBackup: true,
      path: 'images',
    },
  };

  ImagePicker.launchCamera(options, response => {
    console.log('coolio' + response);
    if (response.didCancel) {
      console.log('User cancelled image picker');
    } else if (response.error) {
      console.log('ImagePicker Error: ', response.error);
    } else if (response.customButton) {
      console.log('User tapped custom button: ', response.customButton);
      alert(response.customButton);
    } else {
      setFileData(response.data);
    }
  });
  return fileData;
}
```

I tried to call useCamera() like "< useCamera / >",
I changed the anonymous function to just a function.
I tried to call useCamera() from other part of the code (not from onPress) .
 I tried to use Context,and Redux.

**ALL THE SAME ERROR.**
please help meee,
Thanks!

Comment: Should `LaunchCamera` be capitalised like that? It's not a component.

Comment: you are violating the convention, because LaunchCamera() is a custom hook, it should be named 'useCamera', I don't know changing the name works or not, let's try and let me know

Comment: tried it, did not :(...

Comment: you are violating another rule of hooks too, you called the custom hook inside an `if`, try to call it above `ActionSheet` (https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html) and let me know

Comment: I removed the if, still get the same error

Comment: ```ERROR: Invalid Hook call.Hooks can only be called inside of the body of the function...``` no, remove the `if` does not help, you have to call `const fileData = useCamera()` immediately at the first line of you `functional Component`

Comment: but useCamera() should be called only if a user press the "camera" title in the ActionSheet

Answer (score 0):

I've had this problem before as well what version of React-Native are you using?

React 16.8.0 is the first release to support Hooks. When upgrading, don’t forget to update all packages, including React DOM. React Native supports Hooks since the 0.59 release of React Native.

https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html

Comment: "react": "16.11.0",
    "react-native": "0.62.0",

Answer (score 0):

I see the sign, you call `this.setState`, it means you are using a class-based component.
a react hook can be used only in a functional component.
You have to convert the component which called `LaunchCamera()` (it should be renamed `useCamera()`) to the functional component.

Comment: LaunchCamera() ( which already renamed to useCamera() in my code) is a function. Indeed the function called from a class; is it a problem?

Comment: The component have to be converted is the component which render your <ActionSheet />
you misunderstand this, useCamera is a custom hook, and you call it in a class-based component, this is not allowed

Comment: follow this guide to convert it (https://medium.com/@olinations/10-steps-to-convert-a-react-class-component-to-a-functional-component-with-hooks-ab198e0fa139)

Comment: well..I changed the component which render my <ActionSheet /> to a function, still the same error

Comment: could you post that entire component into the question?

Comment: I edited the question. all the component is there now

Comment: now it look good,  let's try `const data = useCamera();` below `const [fileDate, setFileDate] = useState(null);` and `if (index == 1) { console.log(data) }`

Comment: when I write const data = useCamera();  but its invoke the function. I tried to wrtie const data = () => useCamera(); and I tried   const data = useCamera; 
then to write console.log(data), console.log(data()) all the same ERROR

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210814/discussion-between-foxeye-rinx-and-msm).